# It is about random choice in python

Tags: python, random

I was trying to create the Buffoon's Needle experiment through a simplistic way of using randomness as a replacement of probability. The value of pi can be found from the equation
pi = 2*ln/th where l= length of needle, n = number of times the needle is dropped, t = breadth of lines, h = number of times needle crosses a line.
I have assumed l = t thereby reducing my equation to pi = 2*n/h. 
Now I have made two codes.
Code 1:

```
import math, random
h = 0.0
n = 0.0
for i in range(0,10000):
    a = random.random()
    if a > 0.64:
        h = h+1
    else:
        n = n+1
re = 2*(n+h)/n
print "Value of pi is ", re
err = (math.pi - re)*100/(math.pi)
print "Percentage error is  ", abs(err)
```

Now this one is running fine and giving me good enough results.
But the following code is repeating the same answer over and over again. 
Code 2:

```
import random, time, math
h=1.0
n=1.0
err = 0.0
while err < 0.1:
    a = random.random()
    if a > 0.64:
        h = h+1
    else:
        n = n+1
    re = 2*(n+h)/n
    err = (math.pi - re)*100/(math.pi)
print "Number of attempts is ", n+h
```

Can someone tell me why??

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but your program, in both cases, approximates 2/0.64, not pi. It has nothing to do with Buffon's needle.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop's condition is backwards. It should be:

```
while err > 0.1:
```

You should also set `err` to `1.0` or something higher than `0.1`.

Finally, when calculating the error, you should use `abs`:

```
err = abs(math.pi - re) / (math.pi)
```

Comment: Hi Blender and Antti Haapala thanks for your suggestions. The code is working fine now. I have more problems which I will be posting soon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You want the error to be as big as possible in the beginning, and then loop until it becomes sufficiently small. Use

```
import sys

error = sys.float_info.max
epsilon = 0.1
while err > epsilon:
    ...
```

Also, generally the difference can be negative too, so to get the error you'd want to use abs to only compare the magnitude. Thus we get a more idiomatic program

```
import random, time, math
import sys

h = n = 1.0
err = sys.float_info.max
epsilon = 0.001

while err > epsilon:
    a = random.random()
    if a > 0.64:
        h += 1
    else:
        n += 1

    re = 2 * (n + h) / n
    err = abs((math.pi - re) / math.pi)

print "Value of pi is ", re
print "Number of attempts is ", n + h
```

Comment: No need for `sys.float_info.max` simply use `float('+inf')`.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out issues with your stopping criteria, but your code has a more fundamental flaw.  It is **NOT** Buffon's needle experiment.  You've found a slightly convoluted way to calculate the ratio 2.0 / 0.64. If you ran your program repeatedly and averaged the outcomes, you'd find that the average converges to 3.125, not to Pi.  Buffon's experiment was based on whether or not a needle crossed one of a parallel set of lines based on both the location of the needle's center and the angle at which it fell, neither of which is accounted for in your program.

If you want a relatively simple Monte Carlo way to estimate Pi, generate points randomly over the 2x2 square centered at (0,0), and see what proportion of those points fall within the inscribed circle with unit radius.  The proportion ought to be the same as the ratio of the two areas, Pi / 4, so multiplying the estimated proportion by 4 gives a decent estimate of Pi.  In pseudo-code:

```
count = 0
repeat N times
  x <- U(-1,1)
  y <- U(-1,1)
  if x^2 + y^2 <= 1
    increment count
pi_est <- 4 * count / N
```

where `U(-1,1)` indicates to generate a value uniformly between -1 and 1.